# PowerShell command line embedded into Powershell form.

Tags: forms, powershell, embed

Is is possible to to embed the shell window that appears when you open a `PowerShell` form, inside the form itself?

**Normal form with window:**

[image: Powershell form]

**What I'm looking to achieve:**

[image]

Is this possible? Or are there any methods to achieve a similar effect?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're doing, but there are a few ways you could solve this. I'm assuming in this answer that you're creating the form in PowerShell, not the PowerShell window from the form (which is actually *easer* to manage). If there's something you have that you want to be "click-able", such as a batch file or a shortcut, then you'll need to reference the PowerShell exe and provide it some arguments (such as the location of your script), where you can also specify the window style (see PowerShell help -- PowerShell.exe -?). For this case, you'd probably want to use:

```
powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Be sure to test and ensure that any forms the shell opens are visible.

If what you want to do is create a form, and then put text ON the form, there are a few ways you can do that, too:

1. Create a control (TextBlock would be good), and put data onto the control from your shell, such as the trace messages that would come from your shell for the user normally
2. Create a powershell process, and hook into the standard output stream.

I'm not sure how you'd go about hosting the console window on your screen, because things like windows and forms are managed a little differently than console apps, which run inside an instance of conhost.exe.

Do any of the above techniques meet your criteria?